# How to negate a range in iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I've seen people use the exclamation mark (!) in multiple examples, but when I try to use it I get an error.

The rule I'm trying:

`-A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner 1006 -d ! 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP`

The error:

`Bad argument '192.168.1.0/24'`

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: interesting is the interation with History Expansion.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just as the manpage states:

```
[!] -d, --destination address[/mask][,...]
       Destination  specification.   See  the  description  of  the  -s
       (source)  flag  for  a  detailed description of the syntax.  The
       flag --dst is an alias for this option.
```

That makes it

```
! -d 192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with shady blogs, the syntax has changed for iptables and the exclamation mark went before the flag at some point.

Comment: You can also use it like:  `! -d <URL>`.